# All .PHP pages give 5x error in nginx

Tags: nginx, centos, php

I followed [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-on-centos-8) guide to install Nginx and PHP on a CentOS server. I am able to do things like `php --version` and even use the interactive shell. But inside of `/usr/share/nginx/html/`, I make a PHP file (info.php from the guide) and it gives the default `50x.html` error page. I have not changed anything but what the guide told me to, and I may reinstall CentOS if there isn't a solution.

Any help would be amazing :D

Comment: You should show your nginx and php configuration.

Comment: This Questions must be in a business environment and the business problem seeking installation, configuration or diagnostic help must include the desired end state, the specific problem or error, sufficient information about the configuration and environment to reproduce it, and attempted solutions. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers and are unlikely to get good answers.